# Youtube Leaked Service Connection when setRaetainInstance(true)

Tags: android, youtube-api

I have problems with the following error:

```
04-26 11:41:58.662: E/ActivityThread(10933): Activity MyActivity has leaked ServiceConnection com.google.android.youtube.player.internal.r$e@2cf388d that was originally bound here
```

I have a Fragment and i set the following in onCreate:

```
/**
 * 
 */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    this.setRetainInstance(true);
}
```

I set this because i have a list of youtubevideos with thumbnails and i dont
want these thumbnails to be reloaded everytime the user rotates the screen.
thats just unnecessary traffic.

The following is my adapter for the listview:

```
public class YoutubeListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private List<TutorialEntry> entries = null;
    private List<View> entryViews = null;
    private Map<YouTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeThumbnailLoader> thumbnailViewToLoaderMap = null;
    private LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    private TutorialThumbnailListener thumbnailListener = null;
    private boolean labelsVisible = false;;

    public YoutubeListAdapter(Context context, List<TutorialEntry> entries) {
        this.entries = entries;
        this.entryViews = new ArrayList<View>();
        this.thumbnailViewToLoaderMap = new HashMap<YouTubeThumbnailView, YouTubeThumbnailLoader>();
        this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.thumbnailListener = new TutorialThumbnailListener(this.thumbnailViewToLoaderMap);
        this.labelsVisible = true;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return this.entries.size();
    }

    @Override
    public TutorialEntry getItem(int position) {
        return entries.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TutorialEntry entry = entries.get(position);

        ViewHolder holder = null;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = this.inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tutorials_row, parent, false);

            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.thumbnail = (YouTubeThumbnailView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tutorials_row_thumbnail);
            holder.thumbnail.setTag(entry.getVideoId());
            holder.thumbnail.initialize(Globals.GOOGLE_API_KEY, this.thumbnailListener);
            holder.textViewTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.tutorials_row_title);

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

            YouTubeThumbnailLoader loader = this.thumbnailViewToLoaderMap.get(holder.thumbnail);

            if (loader == null) {
                holder.thumbnail.setTag(entry.getVideoId());
            } else {
                holder.thumbnail.setImageResource(R.drawable.youtube_loading_thumbnail);

                loader.setVideo(entry.getVideoId());
            }
        }

        holder.textViewTitle.setText(entry.getTitle());
        holder.textViewTitle.setVisibility(labelsVisible ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);

        return convertView;
    }

    public void releaseLoaders() {
        for (YouTubeThumbnailLoader loader : this.thumbnailViewToLoaderMap.values()) {
            loader.release();
        }
    }

    public void setLabelVisibility(boolean labelsVisible) {
        this.labelsVisible = labelsVisible;

        for (View view : this.entryViews) {
            view.findViewById(R.id.tutorials_row_title).setVisibility(labelsVisible ? View.VISIBLE : View.GONE);
        }
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {
        private YouTubeThumbnailView thumbnail = null;
        private TextView textViewTitle = null;
    }
}
```

the problem occurs in this line:

```
holder.thumbnail.initialize(Globals.GOOGLE_API_KEY, this.thumbnailListener);
```

can someone help me understand what is happening there and how i can solve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This exception usually comes from not releasing all loaders. From what I can tell, you never call your `releaseLoaders()` method, so since the loaders are just sort of sitting there as the Activity becomes torn down. The way Android is designed, you should release these loaders, else you'll get memory leaks.

Personally, I put my loader releases in my `onstop()` method and it works exquisitely.

```
@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    for (YouTubeThumbnailLoader loader : thumbnailViewToLoaderMap.values()) {
        loader.release();
    }
}
```